Unit test ArgumentOutOfRangeException when compiling my Bowling Code kata
public class Game
{
    private IOutputProvider _outputProvider;
    private List<Frame> frames = new List<Frame>();
    private int currentRoll = 0;

    public Game(IOutputProvider outputProvider)
    {
        _outputProvider = outputProvider;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            frames.Add(new Frame());
        }
    }

    public void StarteSpiel()
    {
        while (!Over())
        {
            _outputProvider.Write("Geben Sie die Anzahl der umgeworfenen Pins ein: ");

            string input = _outputProvider.Read();
            int pins;

            while (!int.TryParse(input, out pins) || pins < 0 || pins > 10)
            {
                _outputProvider.Write("Ungültige Eingabe! Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl zwischen 0 und 10 ein: ");
                input = _outputProvider.Read();
            }

            AddRoll(pins);
        }

        _outputProvider.Write("Spiel beendet! Endpunktzahl: " + TotalScore());
    }

    private void AddRoll(int pins)
    {
        if (Over())
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Das Spiel ist beendet!");
        }

        int frameIndex = GetCurrentFrameIndex();

        if (pins == 10 && currentRoll % 2 == 0 && frameIndex < 9)
        {
            _outputProvider.Write("Herzlichen Glückwunsch, Sie haben einen Strike geworfen!");

            frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[0] = pins;
            frames[frameIndex].IsComplete = true;

            currentRoll += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            if (frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[0] + pins > 10 && frameIndex < 9)
            {
                _outputProvider.Write("Die Summe der beiden Würfe in einem Frame darf nicht mehr als 10 betragen. Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Anzahl Pins ein: ");
                return;
            }

            // Den Wurf zum aktuellen Frame hinzufügen
            if (frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[0] == 0)
            {
                frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[0] = pins;
            }
            else
            {
                frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[1] = pins;
                frames[frameIndex].IsComplete = true; // Frame ist vollständig
            }

            currentRoll++;
        }

        CalculateScores();
        _outputProvider.Write($"Aktuelle Punktzahl: {TotalScore()}");
    }

    private int GetCurrentFrameIndex()
    {
        return currentRoll / 2;
    }

    private int TotalScore()
    {
        int totalScore = 0;
        foreach (var frame in frames)
        {
            totalScore += frame.Score;
        }
        return totalScore;
    }

    private bool Over()
    {
        // Stelle sicher, dass das Spiel 10 Frames hat
        if (frames.Count < 10)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var lastFrame = frames[9];

        if (lastFrame.PinsRolled[0] == 10)
        {
            return lastFrame.PinsRolled.Length == 3 && currentRoll >= 12;
        }

        if (lastFrame.PinsRolled[0] + lastFrame.PinsRolled[1] == 10)
        {
            return currentRoll >= 11;
        }
        return currentRoll >= 20;
    }

    private void CalculateScores()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < frames.Count; i++)
        {
            var frame = frames[i];

            if (frame.IsComplete)
            {
                if (IsStrike(i))
                {
                    CalculateStrikeScore(frame, i);
                }
                else if (IsSpare(i))
                {
                    CalculateSpareScore(frame, i);
                }
                else
                {
                    frame.Score = frame.PinsRolled[0] + frame.PinsRolled[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CalculateStrikeScore(Frame frame, int frameIndex)
    {
        frame.Score = 10 + StrikeBonus(frameIndex);
    }

    private void CalculateSpareScore(Frame frame, int frameIndex)
    {
        frame.Score = 10 + SpareBonus(frameIndex);
    }

    private bool IsStrike(int frameIndex)
    {
        return frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[0] == 10;
    }

    private bool IsSpare(int frameIndex)
    {
        return frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[0] + frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[1] == 10;
    }

    private int StrikeBonus(int frameIndex)
    {
        if (frameIndex + 1 < frames.Count)
        {
            var nextFrame = frames[frameIndex + 1];
            return nextFrame.PinsRolled[0] + (nextFrame.PinsRolled[1] != 0 ? nextFrame.PinsRolled[1] : (frameIndex + 2 < frames.Count ? frames[frameIndex + 2].PinsRolled[0] : 0));
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int SpareBonus(int frameIndex)
    {
        if (frameIndex + 1 < frames.Count)
        {
            return frames[frameIndex + 1].PinsRolled[0];
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

So guys im writing a little game for counting how many pins I bowled over in a bowling game. I´ve written many tests for basically every case that could happen and I just can't fix that my test is failing when throwing only strikes.
The goal is to have 12 litters and 300 points in total in the end. I'm very stuck so it would be nice if someone could help me
This is my Frame class:
public class Frame
{
    public int[] PinsRolled { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }

    public Frame()
    {
        PinsRolled = new int[2];
        IsComplete = false;
    }
}


"I just can't fix that my test is failing when throwing only strikes" - so what have you tried to do, and where are you stuck? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger, checking that it behaves as expected at every point? (It doesn't help that you haven't shown us the test either...)

" System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')"
The error is in this line: "if (frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[0] + pins > 10 && frameIndex < 9)"
The problem is definetly not triggered by how the test is written

When it's throwing the exception, what's the value of frameIndex and what's the value of frames.Count()?

Value of frameIndex is 10 and frames.Count is also 10

Please [edit] your question to add important additional information.

All that information should be in the question, not the comments. The test should be included in the question as a way of reproducing the problem - and if you don't understand what's wrong yet, that probably means you shouldn't be as confident that "the problem is definitely not triggered by how the test is written". (And at the very least, the test would indicate the scenario that causes the problem.)

(Fundamentally though, I suspect the problem is in the handling of the "extra" frame when a strike or spare is scored in the final frame. If you've only got 10 frames in frames, where do you expect the "extra" frame to be stored?)

Final note for now: as Stack Overflow questions are expected to be in English, it would be useful to translate your comments and messages to English too. Don't forget that the purpose of Stack Overflow isn't to solve your problem (that's just a helpful byproduct) - the intention is to build a repository of high-quality questions and answers.

The error happens at the line of
if (frames[frameIndex].PinsRolled[0] + pins > 10 && frameIndex < 9)

because frameIndex is 10 and frames.Count() is also 10. Since indexing starts from 0, this means that valid indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and not 10.
A quick fix to get rid of the index out of bounds issue would be
int frameIndex = GetCurrentFrameIndex();
if (frameIndex >= frames.Count()) {
    return;
}

and it may turn out that this fixes the issue. However, this would be a work-around and you should go deeper and figure out why did you try to reference a frame outside the bounds of frames. Revise Over with a debugger.
